# Redirecting all subdirectories to subdomain with subdirectory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Using NGINX, I want to redirect `domain.com/support/*` to `support.domain.com/*`.

I have the initial `domain.com/support` to `support.domain.com` redirect working, but I'm not sure how to make it dynamic:

```
  server {
    server_name support.domain.com;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.domain.com/support$1 permanent;

    location ^~ /support/ {
        rewrite ^/support/(.*) $scheme://support.domain.com/$1 permanent;
    }
  }
```

If I go to `domain.com/support/page`, it doesn't redirect to `support.domain.com/page`. I'm not sure how to implement that part.

Comment: That looks reasonable at first glance. What is the problem you are having with it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton If I go to `domain.com/support/page`, it doesn't redirect to `support.domain.com/page`. I'm not sure how to implement that part

Comment: So what actually does happen?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No redirect and `domain.com/support/page` just loads, which is an old page structure. The current redirect only explicitly affects `domain.com/support`

Comment: Make sure you restarted nginx. And then post the complete `server` block.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yeah, I restarted it. I updated my post with the `server` block. Thanks

Comment: That `server` block does not have a `server_name` matching your old URL. So your requests are most likely going to some other `server`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hmm I also tried `server_name support.domain.com domain.com/support;`

Comment: `domain.com/support` is not a hostname, so you can't do that. You have to use only the hostname.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I see. So, if I move the `location` rule into the `domain.com` `server` block, would this work with subdirectories beyond just `/support`, i.e. `/support/page`? EDIT: It worked in the correct `server` block! Thanks again